# How to pass line/col number to external editor from grepwin?

Tags: grep, notepad++

After I get search results in grepwin, I would like to open in an external editor notepad++ at specified line/col number so it automatically jumps to that location.

How can I do this?

Ideally, something like:

```
# (inspired by PowerGREP)
notepad++.exe -n%LINE% -c%COL% filetoedit.txt
```

would be nice.

Comment: Are you saying notepad++ already supports that syntax, and you want a way to pass that in, or are you hoping notepad++ or something else has that syntax?

Comment: Notepad++ already supports those command line arguments. Just wondering how to combine grepwin & notepad++ together so they work together better.

Comment: Can you show either the `grep` command or it's output? This will give us something better to go on.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

grepWin 1.5.6 already supports external editors.  Just click "Settings" and use

```
C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe -n%line% "%path%"
```

Note that "line" and "path" must be lower case.

Comment: @Seth  FWIW, yours doesn't work for me but the one in the answer does on grepwin 2.0.6.1006.

Comment: @tbone, so I searched "PowerGrep" and this is the answer Google gave me. Did not realize it was for GrepWIN until i read your comment. So i am deleting my original comment lol